# Listing available online WMS services (Weather, Land Data, Place Names)?

Tags: data, wms

I'm Looking for WMS services freely available to the public to overlay on my application, specifically weather and AIS information.

Perhaps this is a good place to list some available online WMS services you have stumbled across?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

- [Giant list  with status checker from FGDC - US focused - not sea](https://statuschecker.fgdc.gov/)
- [Great US weather WMS source](http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/ogc/)
- A useful resources to find public map services is Geopole (WMS Server repository)- http://geopole.org/ - requires CSW
- [GeoSeer](https://www.geoseer.net) is a search engine for WMS, WFS, WCS, and WMTS services
- a comprehensive and free search engine for WMS, WMTS and WFS services around the world can be found in Spatineo Directory: http://directory.spatineo.com/ The database currently contains more than 13000 spatial web services with 300000+ layers around the world, most of them freely available. For each service there is also basic availability info included each directory service page. For an example see the page of the Open Data service of the Finnish Meteorological Institute http://directory.spatineo.com/service/9096/ **Disclaimer**: Posted by the founder & CTO of Spatineo
- If you are in the US then the National Weather Service provides loads of layers at http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/help/#!section=mapservices
- The [INSPIRE geoportal](http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/) provides a long list of European geographic datasets. Most of them are published as open WMSs.
- ArcGIS Server mapservices that support WMS can be located using an [appropriately worded google search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=%22View+footprint+in%3A%22+%22Supported+Interfaces%3A%22+wms) of: `"View footprint in:" "Supported Interfaces:" wms`
- GEBCO https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/web_map_service/