# WMS weather data for Europe

Tags: data, wms, europe, weather

I am looking for a source of weather data for Europe. I use http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/goes/conus_vis.cgi? and http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi? for the US, but have been unable to find a source for Europe. I saw a similar question here: [Listing available online WMS services (Weather, Land Data, Place Names)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/list-of-available-online-wms-services-weather-land-data-place-names), but it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

For the whole of Europe unlikely.... however

Northern Europe
http://openmetoc.met.no/about.html

It may be possible to build up lots of individual countries (lots of searching required) but the UK for one is limited in one WMS Services and two 'public' access to the weather data.

Comment: The northern Europe link http://openmeteoc.met.no/about.html doesn't work. But there is a similar application using weather data map tiles for Norway at: http://www.senorge.no/

Comment: I do not maintain the web, links will break based on the servers the companies use. see http://www.websitenotworking.com/openmetoc.met.no

Answer (score -1):

There is European weather data here:
http://www.worldclim.org/current

Comment: This page doesn't seem to list any WMS.

Comment: also climate is not weather 'elemental measurements in a given region over long periods of time' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate

Comment: It's a bit harsh to downvote this to -2 though. If you're interested in weather data, this link is useful.  +1