# WMS/WMTS/TILE free for OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers, wms, map-service, wmts

I want to do a web project with OpenLayers 4 to show what I´ve learn at work about web mapping and OL4 (at work we use mapserver with PostgresSQL) but I want to do something basic and with a static website, no backend.

Anyone know of some API that offers WMS, WMTS or TILE for free compatible with OpenLayers 4?

I've found some articles but out of date, in my search, I found this 2 company that seems offers the product I need:

https://www.mapbox.com/

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-openspace/api/

But I don´t understand if they are OL compatible and if they are totally free.

Some advice?

Answer (score 2):

Both of the api you have mentioned are actually another rendering engines, an alternative to OpenLayers. MapBox for example focuses on vector tiles basemaps. Both of them have their own basemap, but trying to display them in OL is illogical.

You can easilly display some of your vector data on top of openStreetMap WMS or WMTS in openLayers for example in geojson format (examples [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html?q=geojson) or [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html?q=geojson))

Any WMS/WMTS in OGC standard is OpenLayers compatible. You just need to read the GetCapabilities document and put that information in the definition of ol.source (example [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image.html?q=wms)). For example it could be that mapserver service at your work.

There is a lot of free web services, it depends on what you are looking for. For example [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/listing-available-online-wms-services-weather-land-data-place-names) is about weather and land data.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I just need a map, at the moment I'm using one that I took from OL4 examples, I saw the question are you talking about but is so old that almost all the website mentioned are not available anymore or the link are broken.

Comment: The OS OpenSpace client is an OpenLayers 2.12 build customised to handle a non-standard WMS which only serves tiles (the WMS parameters and tile size depend on the zoom level).   It's easy to port to OL3/4/5.  OS terms require a non-collapsible attribution and logo.  http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/ol5-os-map-basic-wms.htm